# Mocking of class is not working in Spock Test case

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spock

I am trying write a test case for Rest Post method which gets request object, converts into domain object and saves an object using spring jpa repository.

Folder Structure:

core.jar - domain, repository and daos
core.war - service, spock test, controllers. core.jar is part dependency jar

**Example Request:**

```
public class RequestObject {

    private Long value2;
    private Long value1;

... getters and setters

}
```

**Domain Object**

```
public class DomainObject {

        private Object object1;
        private Object object2;
        private type field1;
        private type field2;
        private long version;
        private date datecreated

    ... getters and setters

    }
```

**Service Method**

```
  @Autowired
  DomainDAO domainDAO; // DomainDAO has domainRepository Autowired

@RequestMapping( value = "/domain", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
public DomainObject saveDomainObject(@RequestBody RequestObject  request)
{
   return domainDAO.saveDomain(buildDomainObject(request))
}

private DomainObject buildDomainObject(RequestObject  request)
{
  DomainObject object = new DomainObject()
  object.setField1(request.getValue2());
  etc ....
}
```

I am to successfully save/update if I using REST Client/SOAP/Swagger to the database. But when I try to write the spock test case with mocking I am getting below errors

**TEST CASE**

```
  void "saveDomainObject success"() {
    setup:
    1 * domainDAO.saveDomain(domainObject) >> {DomainObject}
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(domainRequest);

    when:
    def resp = mockMvc.perform(post("/domain")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .content(json)).andReturn().response
    def content = new JsonSlurper().parseText(resp.contentAsString)
    then:
    println content
  }
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * domainDAO.saveDomain(domainObject) >> {DomainObject}   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * domainDAO.saveDomain(com.test.core.domain.DomainObject@6f27c0ef)


    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionScope.verifyInteractions(InteractionScope.java:78)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.leaveScope(MockController.java:76)
at com.test.core.rest.service.DomainServiceServiceSpec.saveDomainObject success(DomainServiceSpec.groovy:132)
```

I am facing issues to test with save object, i tried with multiple options but still getting the same error. I doubt this is happening since domain object is in different jar, can any one help me to resolve the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `saveDomain(domainObject)`, you are telling Spock to expect the method to be called *with the value in `domainObject`* as the parameter. In your code, however, you're creating a new `DomainObject` and passing *that* to your mock. This is what I think you want:

```
1 * domainDAO.saveDomain(_ as DomainObject) >> { it[0] }
```